# Category of continuous self maps

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids

Is there any way to reconstruct a topological space from the category of its continuous self maps (possibly under some assumptions)?

How can we tell whether a category is the category of continuous self maps of some topological space?

Are there at least existing theorems or frameworks for questions related to these ones?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by category? If maps are morphisms, then wouldn't it be better to call this a monoid, not a category?

Comment: If the question is along the lines of: "What does $S:=C(\Omega,\Omega)$ tell us about $\Omega$?" ($\Omega$ being some nonempty topological space), I think the subset of $S$ consisting of maps with one-point images tells you quite a lot.

Comment: Assuming that you mean the monoid, here are two comments: You cannot distinguish between a one-point space and the empty space in this way, and if $X$ is a nonempty space then you can describe the point set of $X$ as the set of all monoid elements $a$ such that that for every $b$ $a=ab$.

Comment: what are morphisms between continuous maps here?

Comment: sorry for the terminology which seems confusing, I meant monoid indeed. And did  Tom Goodwillie mean the set of a such that ab = ac for every b and c or did I misunderstand? It seems to give the underlying set indeed, I need a bit more thought to see how to retrieve the topology if that's possible

Comment: $a = ab$ for every $b$

Comment: ah yeah, parsed the formula incorrectly and retrieved it in a too complicated way, sorry

Comment: Re. topology: what topology do you give to $C(\Omega,\Omega)$ (compact open presumably)? What relative topology does this give you for $\Omega$ when you regard it as a subspace?

Comment: I'm not sure. If points are closed one can try to generate a topology using the preimages of the set minus singletons or something like that? Not sure yet what's the good way of doing it

Comment: If your only consider the algebraic structure of the monoid, you cannot distinguish between the discrete and trivial topologies (all "abstract" maps are continuous in both cases).

Comment: There are continuums, whose only continuous self maps are the constant maps and identity. You cannot distinguish them having only the algebraic structure (and there is more than one examples with this property).

Comment: In the positive direction see e.g. "Spaces determined by their homeomorphism groups" by E. S. THOMAS, JR  and "On reconstruction of topological spaces from their groups of homeomorphisms" by MATATYAHU RUBIN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the comment of Tom Goodwillie, you can recognize the underlying set and the underlying maps from the monoid. This leads to http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm66/fm6614.pdf.